# How to check in application if the device has been awoken or went to sleep

Tags: android

In my android app I want to receive the notification when the device wakes up
and when the device goes to sleep.
Based on this I have to perform some operations.
Please help.

Please note

> SCREEN_ON / OFF is different. Screen might be OFF but device might
>   still be in wake state as in case of receiving a phone call. When we
>   place the phone against our ear prximity sensor turns off the screen,
>   but the device does not go to sleep.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007721/android-sleep-stages-levels-on-an-android-device

Comment: @Ankit any solution that worked for you?

Answer (score 2):

There is inbuilt IntentFilters that you can capture.

```
Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON
Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF
```

Using service and broadcastreceiver combination you can achieve that you looking for.

You will find complete demo [HERE](http://androidexample.com/Screen_Wake_Sleep_Event_Listner_Service_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=91&aaid=115)

**UPDATE:**

You can use some methods of PowerManager class.

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

if(pm.isScreenOn()){
   // not sleep
}else{
  // sleep
}
```

API level >=20

```
if(pm.isInteractive()){
   // not sleep
}else{
  // sleep
}
```

**Explanation :**

```
public boolean isScreenOn ()
```

Added in API level 7
This method was deprecated in API level 20.
Use `isInteractive()` instead.

Returns true if the device is in an interactive state.

For historical reasons, the name of this method refers to the power state of the screen but it actually describes the overall interactive state of the device. This method has been replaced by `isInteractive()`.

The value returned by this method only indicates whether the device is in an interactive state which may have **nothing to do with the screen being on or off**. To determine the actual state of the screen, use `getState()`.

Returns
`True` if the device is in an interactive state.

Reference [HERE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#isScreenOn%28%29)

Comment: SCREEN_ON / OFF is different. Screen might be OFF but device might still be in wake state as in case of receiving a phone call. When we place the phone against our ear prximity sensor turns off the screen, but the device does not go to sleep.

Answer (score 0):

http://androidexample.com/Screen_Wake_Sleep_Event_Listner_Service_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=91&aaid=115

I think this link solves your question

```
  import android.content.Context;
  import android.content.Intent;
```

> public class AEScreenOnOffReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
>
> ```
>     private boolean screenOff;
>
>     @Override
>     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
>
>         //Toast.makeText(context, "BroadcastReceiver", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>
>
>         if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
>
>             screenOff = true;
>
>         } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
>
>             screenOff = false;
>
>         }
>
>         // Toast.makeText(context, "BroadcastReceiver :"+screenOff, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>
>         // Send Current screen ON/OFF value to service
>         Intent i = new Intent(context, AEScreenOnOffService.class);
>         i.putExtra("screen_state", screenOff);
>         context.startService(i);
>     }
>
> }
> ```